# Does gcc optimize my cycle with condition?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gcc

I have the following cycle:

```
//condition will be set here to true or false

for (int i = 0; i < LARGE_NUMBER; i++) {
    if (condition) {
        //do foo
    } else {
        //do bar
    }
}
```

Assumption: A cycle if faster without a condition than with a condition. (Is this true?)
Question: Will gcc factor out my `if`, if `condition` has been set outside the for cycle, and the cycle itself doesn't touch `condition`?

If not, I should switch the `if` and the `for`, duplicate code, violate DRY, etc.

Comment: if 'condition' is not changing why would you put it inside 'for'?

Comment: @nacho4d: To avoid code duplication (the `for` header, and other statements outside the `if` but inside the `for`)

Comment: Did you declare `condition` as `volatile`?

Comment: @mvds: condition isn'T volatile, else the compiler can't predict it's value.

Comment: I'm very pleased with the answers, +1, thanks for all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For those who don't wish to read a lengthy post, this optimization is called (in LLVM) [Loop Unswitch](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#loop-unswitch).

Why not ask a compiler ?

```
void foo(char* c);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  bool const condition = argc % 2;

  for (int i = 0; i != argc; ++i) {
    if (condition) {
      foo(argv[1]);
    } else {
      foo(argv[0]);
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Is transformed into SSA form (via [LLVM try out](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi)):

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture %argv) {
entry:
  %0 = icmp eq i32 %argc, 0                       ; <i1> [#uses=1]
  br i1 %0, label %bb5, label %bb.nph

bb.nph:                                           ; preds = %entry
  %1 = and i32 %argc, 1                           ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  %toBool = icmp eq i32 %1, 0                     ; <i1> [#uses=1]
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds i8** %argv, i64 1   ; <i8**> [#uses=1]
  br i1 %toBool, label %bb3.us, label %bb3

bb3.us:                                           ; preds = %bb3.us, %bb.nph
  %i.07.us = phi i32 [ %4, %bb3.us ], [ 0, %bb.nph ] ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  %3 = load i8** %argv, align 8                   ; <i8*> [#uses=1]
  tail call void @_Z3fooPc(i8* %3)
  %4 = add nsw i32 %i.07.us, 1                    ; <i32> [#uses=2]
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %4, %argc               ; <i1> [#uses=1]
  br i1 %exitcond, label %bb5, label %bb3.us

bb3:                                              ; preds = %bb3, %bb.nph
  %i.07 = phi i32 [ %6, %bb3 ], [ 0, %bb.nph ]    ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  %5 = load i8** %2, align 8                      ; <i8*> [#uses=1]
  tail call void @_Z3fooPc(i8* %5)
  %6 = add nsw i32 %i.07, 1                       ; <i32> [#uses=2]
  %exitcond8 = icmp eq i32 %6, %argc              ; <i1> [#uses=1]
  br i1 %exitcond8, label %bb5, label %bb3

bb5:                                              ; preds = %bb3, %bb3.us, %entry
  ret i32 0
}
```

Not too readable perhaps, so let me point out what's here:

- `entry`: check if `argc` is equal to 0, if it is, go to `bb5` (exit) else go to `bb.nph`
- `bb.nph`: compute the value of `condition`, if it's true, go to `bb3.us` else go to `bb3`
- `bb3.us` and `bb3`: loops for the true and false condition respectively
- `bb5`: exit

A compiler can pretty much transform your code how it wants, as long as the effect is similar to what you asked for. In this case, it has effectively rewritten the code as:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  if (argc != 0)
  {
    int i = 0;
    if (argc % 2) {
      do {
        foo(argv[1]);
        ++i;
      } while (i != argc);
    } else {
      do {
        foo(argv[0]);
        ++i;
      } while (i != argc);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It's a form of Loop Invariant Optimization, combined here with a first check to avoid computing the condition if the loop is not going to get executed.

For those of us who would think the first solution is clearer, we're quite happy to have the compiler do the nitty gritty optimization for us!

Comment: *Quick Note* It could get even uglier, in fact, if the compiler was going into loop unrolling (to avoid checking if it must keep looping at each iteration). If you want to look at manual unrolling, look up Duff's Device, and you'll probably agree that it's better if the compiler does it.

Answer (score 8):

Any decent optimizing compiler will do this if `condition` can be proved to not change during the iteration.

Furthermore, even if the compiler does not in fact do this, you would do well to support your decision to rewrite the code to a less-human-readable form with hard data from profiling. *Don't optimize prematurely.* It isn't worth it to give readers of the code a "huh?" moment in order to shave off a few milliseconds (and "readers" definitely includes yourself at a future time).

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't advocate to take any action here, by the usual "premature optimization" arguments. Keeping the code clear is most important, and if the whole program is too slow, you may want to profile and find the actual bottlenecks (that you usually can't guess) after the program has been thoroughly debugged.

Even if the compiler does not optimize this particular case for you, you may want to know that CPU do some form of [*branch prediction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) which will greatly reduce the time needed to process the condition in case the condition is predictable.

Indeed, most CPU process instructions in a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) and by the time the jump address has to be determined, the condition variable may be unknown. This would cause a *pipeline stall*, and this is where most modern processors try to guess (smartly in fact) where the program will jump. If the condition variable is indeed known (as it is in your case), the guess will be perfect.

So I doubt that even with a "dumb" compiler, you would actually see a difference between the two options, at least on modern machines.

Comment: actually most compiler should write two loops here, depending on the value of condition, if it can be proven that condition does not change within the execution of the loop. It does not invalidate what you are saying.

Comment: Totally agree with Matthieu. +1 for the branch prediction which in this case indeed makes the discussion moot.